# OAuth::Unauthorized: 401 using dropbox-api gem in Rails 3.2 console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dropbox-api

I am trying to authorize using dropbox-api gem just in the Rails console

Here's how I fired it up in the console:

But I keep on getting `401 Unauthorized` error upon accessing via `oauth_verifier`

Here's the gem that I am using: https://github.com/futuresimple/dropbox-api

```
> Dropbox::API::Config.app_key    = MY_APP_TOKEN
> Dropbox::API::Config.app_secret = MY_APP_SECRET
> consumer = Dropbox::API::OAuth.consumer(:authorize)
> request_token = consumer.get_request_token
> request_token.authorize_url(:oauth_callback => 'http://localhost:3000/callback/dropbox')
> hash = { oauth_token: request_token.token, oauth_token_secret: request_token.secret}
> request_token  = OAuth::RequestToken.from_hash(consumer, hash)
> result = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => request_token.token)
```

ERROR:

```
1.9.3-p448 :019 > access_token = request_token.get_access_token(:oauth_verifier => request_token.token)
OAuth::Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/consumer.rb:216:in `token_request'
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/oauth-0.4.7/lib/oauth/tokens/request_token.rb:18:in `get_access_token'
    from (irb):19
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/xiruki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Any workarounds will be appreciated.

Comment: To verify, did you actually visit the authorize URL and authorize the app before executing the `get_access_token` call?

Comment: Not yet let me try that one and please wait for my feedback. Thanks for taking time :]

Comment: Hi smarx thank you, I just need to 'allow' it first.

Answer (score 0):

Moving my comment to an answer:

Be sure to actually visit the authorize URL and "allow" the app before trying to call `get_access_token`.